# Using getPackageManager in android

Tags: android

i am unable to use **GetPackageManager** in my **BroadcastReceiver**, i am getting the error "*The method getPackageManager() is undefined for the type ReceiverSchedulerDaily*". below is my code

```
public class ReceiverSchedulerDaily extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // clean all app caches
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        Method[] methods = pm.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method m : methods) {
            if (m.getName().equals("freeStorageAndNotify")) {
                try {
                    long desiredFreeStorage = Long.MAX_VALUE;
                    m.invoke(pm, desiredFreeStorage, null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        //
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the line:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
```

Use this:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
```

The code you are using was probably used in an Activity before, which is a subclass of Context. But you are using it in a BroadCastReceiver now, which does not extend Context. So you have to use a Context reference instead, to get the reference to the Package Manager system service.

Comment: hey can you have a look on this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218650/cancel-a-toast-android @Daniel